# Почему после обучения логистической регрессии не могу вызвать "logit"

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Обучил логистическую регрессию

```
%%time
    logit = LogisticRegression(n_jobs=1, random_state=17)
    logit.fit (X_train_sparse, y_train)
```

Ответ:

```
Wall time: 8.54 s
```

После вызова logit

```
logit или
logit.predict(X_test,_sparse[0, :])
```

у меня ошибка:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-cefa38cc2297> in <module>
----> 1 logit

NameError: name 'logit' is not defined
```

Почему я не могу вызвать logit, если обучение прошло без ошибок?

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вы не договариваете. Попробуйте выполнить следующий блок:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

%%time
logit = LogisticRegression(n_jobs=1, random_state=17)
logit.fit (X, y)
Wall time: 998 µs

logit
Out[46]: 
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='warn', n_jobs=1,
          penalty='l2', random_state=17, solver='warn', tol=0.0001,
          verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

Comment: Выполнил это код, но теперь после блока: %%time
...
logit.fit (X, y), у меня идут warnings: C:\Users\ivan1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py:433: FutureWarning: Default solver will be changed to 'lbfgs' in 0.22. Specify a solver to silence this warning.
  FutureWarning)
C:\Users\ivan1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py:460: FutureWarning: Default multi_class will be changed to 'auto' in 0.22. Specify the multi_class option to silence this warning.
  "this warning.", FutureWarning). Ошибка связанная с "logit" не пропала